# unresponsive onclick event in OpenLayer.Popup.FramedCloud

Tags: html, events, popup, onclick, openlayers

I'm using OpenLayer.Popup.FramedCloud from OpenLayer (JavaScript Mapping Library).
in the popup constructor there is a parameter called contentHTML.
I put there html button with onlick event:

```
contentHTML = "<button type='button' onclick='alert()'>Hello</button>";
```

from some reason the button doesn't respond to a click.
Why? Is there a solution for this?

Maybe this is because the web page is uploaded in Winform WebBrowser?
I noticed that when I upload the page with a regular browser (chrome) everything's working
but not in Winform WebBrowser.

the complete popup object:

```
        var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat);
        var size = new OpenLayers.Size(300,200)
        var htmlString = "<button type='button' onclick='alert()'>Hello</button>";
    popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("popup", 
                                              lonlat, 
                                              size, 
                                              htmlString,                 
                                              anchor=null,   
                                              closeButtonX =false);         
        popup.id = callId;
        g_waze_map.map.addPopup(popup);
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you upload an example to http://JSFiddle.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm developing and using OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud and works fine (even with your contentHTML). Here is my code:

```
// i.e. x = 100, y = 300;

var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
    "getfeature",
    map.getLonLatFromPixel(new OpenLayers.Pixel(x,y)),
    new OpenLayers.Size(300,200),
    "<button type='button' onclick='alert()'>Hello</button>",
    null,
    true
);
popup.autoSize = false;
map.addPopup(popup);
```

The popup automatically open and shows me the button. When I click on it, an alert is displayed with text 'undefined'.

Comment: Can you post how are you creating the popup? Edit your main post please. Thanks!

Comment: @Day_Dreamer What about changing the last two parameters of your FramedCloud constructor and using 'null' and 'true' respectively?

Comment: Try to define a basic Popup using OpenLayers.Popup class; use your own 'contenthtml' to fill the new popup and display it. Just to know if the problem is because of FramedCloud class http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Popup-js.html. Use the example I've provided in the previous link.

Comment: The problem is probably with Winform web browser. See my post edition

Comment: I'm not familiarized with Winform WebBrowsers. Is it a C# control? I can't help you. I hope someone know about them and can help you :)